# Excel date calculation to handle next occurring date based on 2 entry field

Tags: excel

[image: Entry fields]

Trying to get a few things to happen from these fields

with the above entry fields I am trying to get excel to take the value from the top cell and force this as the day value for the date however if the value is higher than the end of the month eg: 31 on a 30 day month it returns 30 instead.

Then after that if the request date comes 1 day before the above day or on or after that day in the month eg: if request is `09/02/2024 or` 10/02/2024`or`15/02/2024`, and the month day field has` 10`it should add`1` month to the request date but still return the day from the month date field. otherwise return the date from the request field with the month day as the day value.

Basically if a request comes in 1 day before the month day or on/after this day add 1 month to the request date and and use the month day for the day value. otherwise just add the month day value to the day value of the request date.

I almost have this working and counting for all issues, the only issue I have is if the month day is is larger than the days in the month from the request date it goes to the next month instead of keeping the month, everything else seems to work.

I have 2 formulas working together to make this work

A Manual next month with my month day - This is in B20

=IF(B4 > DAY(EOMONTH(B5,1)), EOMONTH(B5,1), DATE(YEAR(B5), MONTH(B5) + 1, DAY(B4)))

then a calc to handle the other stuff - This is in B19

=IF(AND(B4 = 1, DAY(B5) = DAY(EOMONTH(B5, 0))), EDATE(B20, 1), IF(B4 <= DAY(B5), B20, IF(B4 > DAY(EOMONTH(B5, 0)), EDATE(B20,0), IF(B4 - DAY(B5) = 1, B20, EDATE(B20, -1)))))

If anybody can assist so I can resolve this that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I removed what looked like invalid day functions to help clean up code.

[Updated image to show full table with results shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhPxx.png)

So a below table shows examples of what should occur and what doesn't work as mentioned above it seem to only have issues with the end of month dates

| Monthaversay | request date | Next Monthaversary | Current code work for these |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 10/03/2024 | 15/03/2024 | Works |
| 15 | 20/03/2024 | 15/04/2024 | Works |
| 15 | 15/03/2024 | 15/04/2024 | Works |
| 15 | 14/03/2024 | 15/04/2024 | Works |
| 1 | 29/02/2024 | 01/04/2024 | Works |
| 1 | 31/03/2024 | 01/05/2024 | Works |
| 1 | 30/03/2024 | 01/04/2024 | Works |
| 1 | 25/03/2024 | 01/04/2024 | Works |
| 31 | 01/02/2024 | 29/02/2024 | Works |
| 31 | 01/03/2024 | 31/03/2024 | Does not work - returns 30/03/2024 |
| 31 | 30/04/2024 | 31/05/2024 | Works |
| 31 | 30/03/2024 | 30/04/2024 | Does not work - returns 30/03/2024 |
| 31 | 29/02/2024 | 31/03/2024 | Works |
| 30 | 01/02/2024 | 29/02/2024 | does not work - returns 30/03/2024 |
| 30 | 01/03/2024 | 30/03/2024 | Works |
| 30 | 29/03/2024 | 30/04/2024 | Works |
| 30 | 31/03/2024 | 30/04/2024 | Works |

I hope this clears everything up more, the absolute simplest way I can explain the underlying rule is if request receive date is 1 day before the monthly anniversary, equal to or after it, move to the next months monthly anniversary otherwise use this months monthly anniversary.

Comment: Is it the case that `Monthaversary Date` is in `B4`. If so, what is the actual date in that cell, or are you applying the `DAY` function inappropriately?  Also, please provide examples of various inputs and the problematic and desired outputs. Preferably in a table and not as free-flowing text.

Comment: I have updated the post and included a table hope this helps clarify everything. 

B4 is only a day of month value entered into the sheet as people using the current sheet keep making error on what the next monthaversary should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But from what you have written, the calculated `Next Monthaversary` should be either the Monthaversary date of the current month or of the next month.

***Edit: It seems from your comments that the `Next Monthaversary` date should rather be the first `Monthaversary` date that exceeds the `Request date` by at least one (1) day.***

I used a **Table** with `Structured References` (so I don't have to fill/down the formula), and I also used the `Let` function to make things more understandable (at least, to me).
*If your version of Excel is prior to 2021 and lacks the `LET` function, the formula can be rewritten without it*

```
=LET(
    rd, [@[request date]],
    ma, [@Monthaversay],
    y, YEAR(rd),
    m, MONTH(rd),
    d, DAY(rd),
    currMA, MIN(DATE(y, m + {1, 0}, ma * {0, 1})),
    nextMA, MIN(DATE(y, m + {2, 1}, ma * {0, 1})),
    next2MA, MIN(DATE(y, m + {3, 2}, ma * {0, 1})),
    allMA, VSTACK(currMA, nextMA, next2MA),
    XLOOKUP(TRUE, (allMA - rd) > 1, allMA)
)
```

[image]

*(Formula for older versions of Excel)*

```
=IF(
    (MIN(DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2) + {1, 0}, A2 * {0, 1})) - B2) > 1,
    MIN(DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2) + {1, 0}, A2 * {0, 1})),
    IF(
        (MIN(DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2) + {2, 1}, A2 * {0, 1})) - B2) > 1,
        MIN(DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2) + {2, 1}, A2 * {0, 1})),
        MIN(DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2) + {3, 2}, A2 * {0, 1}))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I noticed 1 error in the table I provided, Row 7 should return 01/04/2024 as there is more 1 day between the request date and the next monthaversary

The reason for Row 5&6 having an extra month added on is because if the next day is technically the next monthaversary we add 1 month. this seems to work for everything else.

Comment: eg: if with the code you provided I use 15 in Column A and 14/02/2024 in column B we get 15/03/2024 which is correct. but if I use  1 in column A and 31/01/2024 in column B we get 01/02/2024 instead of the desired outcome of 01/03/2024

Comment: @Ryan So to put it another way, you are really testing that the **date** and not the *day* of the next monthaversary date be more than one day ahead of the request date. I will edit my answer

Comment: yes I think we are on the same page. the date of the next month anniversary is the next time the Day from A1 appears after the request date but if the request date is 1 day before the next monthly anniversary that should be coming up or on the same day it skips to the next month

Comment: @Ryan Did you check my edit of an hour ago?

Comment: This is amazing Thank you so much! it looks good to me, have a friend going to double check in a couple of days. Hopefully I've missed nothing and we have fixed it! :) Much appreciate your help